# Angular Reactive Forms - ngfor set value in html based on promise

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a component which gets a list of results then feeds one of the values to a child component in a form which is using angular reactive forms. I set the value in the html form and I can see it but it seems to not have registered as part of the formgroups values as everytime i submit the form threadId shows as null, I guess it is because it displays after the view inits but I cant seem to figure  out how to set it or make the form realise that there is a value there

```
    ngOnInit() {
        this.loadForm();
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.loadForm();
    }


    loadForm(): void {
        this.form = this.fb.group({
            threadId: [''],       
            comment: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(1)])]
        });
        this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(data => console.log('form changes', data));
    }
```

and the html is

````
..ngfor item here feeds into this

          <form [formGroup]="form">
          <input formControlName="threadID" value="{{ item.threadID }}" />   
          <textarea formControlName="comment" type="text" placeholder="{{ 'COMMENT_REPLY' | translate }} "></textarea>    
          <button [disabled]="form.invalid" (click)="submit()"  type="submit" expand="block" color="secondary" fill="outline">
            poost
          </button>   
        </form>   ```
````

Comment: JavaScript is case-sensitive. `threadId != threadID`. And you don't set a form control value using value="{{ ...}}'. You set it using the FormControl's setValue() method. The point of truth is the model. The view is generated based on the model. Initializing the form twice is also really not a good idea.

Comment: Its not possible to use setValue because the value only gets set from the parent ngFor loop

Comment: Wait, you have many items, but a single form to edit all of them? Something else is wrong there, too. The data displayed by the ngFor comes from your component. So your component can call setValue on the form control.